# Console.log() not logging the id of a div when clicked

Tags: reactjs, console.log

I have 2 simple functions(app,generateList).
The problem that is occurring is that whenever I click the rendered div from generateList then sometimes I get the console logged value of the id of that div but then most of the time I'm getting a blanked value that is being logged. If I click on a div with another id, that id is logged but then if clicked again, that id isn't logged but a blank value is logged.

Why is this happening?
[image]

The app function is as follows:

```
[![import React from 'react';
import GenerateList from './generate_list';

function App() {

const \[notes,SetNotes\] = React.useState(\[{id:1,value:""}\]); 

function addNote()
{
  SetNotes(prevItem => {return (\[...prevItem,{id:prevItem\[prevItem.length-1\].id+1,value:""}\])})
}

function clicked(event)
{
  console.log(event.target.id);
}



const list = notes.map(item => {return <GenerateList key={item.id} value={item.id} func={clicked} />});


return (
  <div className='container'>
    <div className='sidebar'>
      <button onClick={addNote} >Add</button>
      {list}
    </div>
  </div>
  );
}

export default App;][1]][1]
```

The generate list function is as follows:

```
import React from "react"

export default function GenerateList(props)
{
  return(<div  onClick={props.func} className="note_row" id={props.value}>
    <h3>Note {props.value}</h3>
  </div>)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that the `<h3>` is the event target, not the `<div>`.  So one simple change could be to add the `id` to that instead:

```
export default function GenerateList(props)
{
  return(<div  onClick={props.func} className="note_row">
    <h3 id={props.value}>Note {props.value}</h3>
  </div>)
}
```

Alternatively, you don't even really need to worry about events and targets if all you need is that value.  Just send the value to the function:

```
export default function GenerateList(props)
{
  return(<div  onClick={() => props.func(props.value)} className="note_row">
    <h3>Note {props.value}</h3>
  </div>)
}
```

And log the value being sent:

```
function clicked(id)
{
  console.log(id);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Both of your solutions worked.
However, I tweaked something in mine and that worked too.
My h3 was taking up the whole space inside the div, so I thought I was clicking the div but in reality, I was clicking the h3 part and that had no onClick function associated with it and that's why the blank error. On removing its margin and resizing it, I was able to click on the div and get its value successfully.